# I have to compare /verify the values from the user input with the previous one that was saved in the database in a login form. Has to display a msg

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a form which will display a error message if the input data does not match with the one saved in the memory.
The input field has to display a  SVG icon(X) and a red border if the credentials are wrong, and a green border with a SVG (V) icon, if it matches the one all ready saved in the system.

This is what I did so far.

Can you help me with advice, and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form"),
  userField = form.querySelector(".user"),
  user = userField.querySelector("input"),
  passwordField = document.querySelector(".pass"),
  pass = passwordField.querySelector("input"),
  messages = form.querySelector(".msg__display"),
  botton = form.querySelector("#btn");

var validUser = "new_user"
var validPassword = 123456789

form.addEventListener("submit", function () {

  if (user.value == validUser && pass.value == validPassword) {
    userField.classList.add("success");
    userField.classList.remove("fail");
    passwordField.classList.add("success");
    passwordField.classList.remove("fail");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Succesfully Login";

    return true;

  } else {

    checkInputs();
    return false;
  }

})




function checkInputs() {

  if (user.value.length < 1 || user.value == null) {
    userField.classList.add("fail");
    userField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.classList.remove("display_password");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a username";
  } else {
    userField.classList.add("fail");
    userField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.classList.remove("display_password");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a valid username";
  }

  if (pass.value.length < 1 || pass.value == null) {
    passwordField.classList.add("fail");
    passwordField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_password");
    messages.classList.remove("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a password";
  } else {
    passwordField.classList.add("fail");
    passwordField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_password");
    messages.classList.remove("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a valid password";
  }

  if (user.value != validUser && pass.value != validPassword) {
    userField.classList.add("fail");
    userField.classList.remove("success");
    passwordField.classList.add("fail");
    passwordField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a valid user or a valid password";
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#login-container {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: .5em;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(88, 167, 236), rgb(180, 198, 214), rgb(180, 198, 214));
  padding: 3em 2.5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px #424241;
  text-align: justify;
}


.input-field{
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}


input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .5em 1.5em .5em .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
}


.form-control {
  position: relative;
}

.input-field i{
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  right: .8em;
  display: none;
}

.fa-check {
  color: green;
}

.fa-times{
  color: red;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  background: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: 1em 0 .2em 0;
  padding: .5em 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover{
  background-color: #70db70;
  color: white;
}

.message .msg__display {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
}



/*Message  classes*/

.form-control.success input {
  border: 3px solid green;

}
.form-control.fail input {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check {
  display: block;
}
.form-control.fail i.fa-times {
  display: block;
}


.message .msg__display.display_user {
 display: block;
}
.message .msg__display.display_password {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="login-container">

    <form id="form" action="#">

      <div class="input-field">

        <div class="form-control user">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input id="username" class="input" type="text">
          <i class="fas fa-check u_check"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times u_decline"></i>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="input-field">

        <div class="form-control pass">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input id="password" class="input" type="password">
          <i class="fas fa-check p_check"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times p_decline"></i>

        </div>

      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">

      <div id="msg" class="message">
        <p class="msg__display">fail</p>

      </div>

  </div>


  </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please also describe the problem you currently have. Which part is not working? Is there an error message? Does the code not work? Are there messages in the browser console which can help?

Comment: The problem is that it does not show me and display the right message and error class and it doesn't compare the values that I enter in the input fields with the one all ready saved in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your form already behaves as expected but it's sent even if it's invalid. You can see the red borders and the error messages for short moment before the page reloads.

You have to prevent the submit if the input is invalid. You can call `preventDefault()` on the submit event for this:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form"),
  userField = form.querySelector(".user"),
  user = userField.querySelector("input"),
  passwordField = document.querySelector(".pass"),
  pass = passwordField.querySelector("input"),
  messages = form.querySelector(".msg__display"),
  botton = form.querySelector("#btn");

var validUser = "new_user"
var validPassword = 123456789

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  if (user.value == validUser && pass.value == validPassword) {
    userField.classList.add("success");
    userField.classList.remove("fail");
    passwordField.classList.add("success");
    passwordField.classList.remove("fail");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Succesfully Login";
    return true;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
    return false;
  }
})

function checkInputs() {
  if (user.value.length < 1 || user.value == null) {
    userField.classList.add("fail");
    userField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.classList.remove("display_password");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a username";
  } else {
    userField.classList.add("fail");
    userField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.classList.remove("display_password");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a valid username";
  }

  if (pass.value.length < 1 || pass.value == null) {
    passwordField.classList.add("fail");
    passwordField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_password");
    messages.classList.remove("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a password";
  } else {
    passwordField.classList.add("fail");
    passwordField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_password");
    messages.classList.remove("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a valid password";
  }

  if (user.value != validUser && pass.value != validPassword) {
    userField.classList.add("fail");
    userField.classList.remove("success");
    passwordField.classList.add("fail");
    passwordField.classList.remove("success");
    messages.classList.add("display_user");
    messages.textContent = "Please insert a valid user or a valid password";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#login-container {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: .5em;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(88, 167, 236), rgb(180, 198, 214), rgb(180, 198, 214));
  padding: 3em 2.5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px #424241;
  text-align: justify;
}


.input-field{
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}


input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: .5em 1.5em .5em .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
}


.form-control {
  position: relative;
}

.input-field i{
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  right: .8em;
  display: none;
}

.fa-check {
  color: green;
}

.fa-times{
  color: red;
}

form label {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
}

form input[type="submit"] {
  background: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: 1em 0 .2em 0;
  padding: .5em 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover{
  background-color: #70db70;
  color: white;
}

.message .msg__display {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
}



/*Message  classes*/

.form-control.success input {
  border: 3px solid green;

}
.form-control.fail input {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check {
  display: block;
}
.form-control.fail i.fa-times {
  display: block;
}


.message .msg__display.display_user {
 display: block;
}
.message .msg__display.display_password {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="login-container">

    <form id="form" action="#">

      <div class="input-field">

        <div class="form-control user">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input id="username" class="input" type="text">
          <i class="fas fa-check u_check"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times u_decline"></i>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="input-field">

        <div class="form-control pass">
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input id="password" class="input" type="password">
          <i class="fas fa-check p_check"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times p_decline"></i>

        </div>

      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">

      <div id="msg" class="message">
        <p class="msg__display">fail</p>

      </div>

  </div>


  </form>

  </div>
```